# Show: Only bounded solution for $\kappa=1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$$
\frac{d}{dT}\left\{(1-T)^2\frac{d\Psi}{dT}\right\}+\left(2+\frac{\lambda}{1-T^2}\right)\Psi=0,
$$
where $T=\tanh x$.

It is said that the only bounded solution for $\lambda=-\kappa^2 ~(<0)$ occurs if $\kappa=1$ and the corresponding solution is proportional to $-\operatorname{sech}x$.

How can one see that?

When writing $'=\frac{d}{dT}$, the equation reads
$$
(1-T^2)\Psi''-2T\Psi'+\left(2+\frac{\lambda}{1-T^2}\right)\Psi=0
$$
which is the Legendre differential equation
$$
(1-T^2)\Psi''-2T\Psi'+\left(n(n+1)-\frac{m^2}{1-T^2}\right)\Psi=0\tag{*}
$$
for $n=1$ and $m=\kappa$.

It is known that the equation $(*)$ has the general solution
$$
\Psi(T)=AP_n^m(T)+BQ_n^m(T),
$$
where
$$
P_n^m(T)=(1-T^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dT^m}P_n(T),\qquad P_n(T)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dT^n}(T^2-1)^n
$$
and
$$
Q_n^m(T)=(1-T^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dT^m}Q_n(T),\qquad Q_n(T)=\frac{1}{2}P_n(T)\ln\frac{1+T}{1-T}.
$$

If I now choose $n=1$ and $m=\kappa$, what I get is:

$$\Psi(T)=AP_1^\kappa(T)+BQ_1^\kappa(T)$$,
with
$$
\begin{align*}
P_1^\kappa(T)&=(1-T^2)^{\kappa/2}\frac{d^\kappa}{dT^\kappa}T,\\
Q_1^\kappa(T)&=(1-T^2)^{\kappa/2}\frac{d^\kappa}{dT^\kappa}\left(\frac{T}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+T}{1-T}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$$

So, at least for $P_1^\kappa$ we have that
$$
P_1^\kappa(T)=\begin{cases}(1-T^2)^{1/2}=\operatorname{sech}x, & \kappa=1\\0, & \kappa>1\end{cases}
$$

and so I guess $\kappa=1$ is the only meaningful choice here and we also have that at least $AP_1^1(T)$ is proportional to $\operatorname{sech}x$.

Comment: What is $x$ in "proportional to $-\operatorname{sech} x$"?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that $T=\tanh x$. I added it.

Comment: What is $\frac{d^\kappa T}{dT^\kappa}$ for $1<\kappa<2$? Is it $0$? If $\kappa\geq 2$ then I would expect it to vanish by the rule $D^\kappa T = D^{\kappa-2}D^2 T = D^{\kappa-2} 0$ (where $D^m = \frac{d^m}{dT}$).

Comment: I don't know what happens for $1<\kappa <2$. In fact, I thought that $\kappa$ would be integers only. -- In the book which I am reading, it is said that for the equation $$\frac{d}{dT}\left\{(1-T^2)\frac{d\Psi}{dT}\right\}(N(N+1)+\frac{\lambda}{1-T^2})\Psi=0 $$ the only bounded solutions for $T\in [-1,1]$ and $\lambda=-\kappa^2$  occur when $\kappa=n, n=1,2,\ldots,N$ and that these solutions are proportional to the associated Legendre function $P_N^n(T)$. Actually, I do not know why these are the only bounded solutions.

Comment: On the other hand, since the general solution is as mentioned in the post, are there any other (bounded) solutions at all? I am wondering why the $Q_n^m$ terms are not mentioned in that book...